# InstallShield: copy sources locally

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, basic-msi

How can I copy the installation sources to the local drive so that the original media is not required for a repair installation?

This is a Basic MSI project.

Comment: Exact Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120066/installshield-copy-sources-locally ?

Comment: Deleted the other question - it was an accidental double submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browse to **Releases > Product Configuration > Release Configuration**, click on the **Setup.exe** tab and set **Cache MSI Locally** to **Yes**

Comment: Ah, that looks like exactly what I want. However, the setting is disabled. I noticed in the help, "This setting is enabled for releases that do not have the .msi file available in the same folder as the setup.exe file on the target system." Not sure what this means. Any ideas?

Comment: It's enabled for all my single-exe, single-msi and downloader installs in IS2009 Premier, maybe try the IS forums. You'll usually get a better response there than on SO

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure since I don't have the right version of Installshield available. Try verifying that the "Web Type" property is set to "One Executable" for the release.

Alternatively create a new release via the Build => Release Wizard... menu option and test out various options. For example a network image with compressed files without the setup.exe launcher.